# Unexpected result on relationship filtering using multiple Laravel scopes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I'm trying to filter a relationship inside my `User` model. A user can attend courses, which has points bound to them.

Users can earn these points by attending the courses. This is a `BelongsToMany` relationship.

I'm tried creating a scope in this `User` model that would only include the **attended** courses in a range of years.

```
/**
 * Retrieves the courses which the user has attended
 */
public function attendedCourses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_attendees');
}

/**
 * Searches the user model
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
 * @param array                                 $years
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeAttendedCoursesInYears(Builder $builder, array $years)
{
    # Filter on the years
    $callback = function($q) use ($years) {
        foreach ($years as $year) {
            $q->year($year);
        }
    };

    return $builder->with(['attendedCourses' => $callback]);
}
```

In my `Course` model, I have a scope that filters on the year that course was in.

```
public function scopeYear(Builder $query, int $year)
{
    return $query->whereYear('end_date', $year);
}
```

With this `attendedCoursesInYears` scope I hoped I could then calculate the amount of points for each user by summing up the course points, using other scopes on the `Course` model.

```
public function scopeExternal(Builder $query, bool $flag = true)
{
    $categoryIsExternal = function($query) use ($flag) {
        $query->external($flag);
    };

    return $query->whereHas('category', $categoryIsExternal);
}
```

In my `CourseCategory` modal, the scope looks like this:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include external categories.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 *
 * @param bool                                  $flag
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeExternal(Builder $query, $flag = true)
{
    return $query->where('type', '=', $flag ? 'Extern' : 'Intern');
}
```

For calculating this, I tried doing something like this.

```
# Retrieve all the active users
$users = User::all()->attendedCoursesInYears($years);
$test = $users->find(123);

# Calculate the points
$test->attendedCourses()->external(false)->sum('points');
```

This however returned the total sum of all courses.

The use of a scope is the only option here, as I can see. I want to create custom attributes from these values using accessors like this. This so I could easily sort the calculated values.

```
/**
 * The users internal course points
 *
 * @param array $years The years to look for attended courses
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getInternalPointsAttribute() : float
{
    return $this->attendedCourses()->external(false)->sum('points');
}
```

The only problem here is the year filter. I was hoping I could filter the User collection before calling the accessor like my first example.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm currently using this workaround. This seems so bad, because I'm repeating so much code.

```
/**
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
 *
 * @param array                                 $years
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
public function scopeWithPoints(Builder $builder, array $years = [])
{
    # Join all columns
    $builder->join('user_roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'user_roles.id')
            ->leftJoin('course_attendees', 'users.id', '=', 'course_attendees.user_id');

    # Join the course table for the years
    $builder->leftJoin('courses', function(JoinClause $join) use ($years) {
        # Join the courses table with year filters
        $join->on('course_attendees.course_id', '=', 'courses.id');

        # Apply the filters if available
        !empty($years) and $join->whereIn(DB::raw('YEAR(courses.end_date)'), $years);
    });

    # Select the columns
    $builder->select('users.*')->groupBy('users.id');

    # Sums
    $internalPoints = 'SUM(courses.points_internal)';
    $externalPoints = 'SUM(courses.points_external)';

    # Select the points
    $builder->selectRaw('COALESCE(' . $internalPoints . ', 0) as internal_points');
    $builder->selectRaw('COALESCE(' . $externalPoints . ', 0) as external_points');
    $builder->selectRaw('COALESCE(' . $internalPoints . ' + ' . $externalPoints . ', 0) as total_points');

    # Sum up the course points
    return $builder;
}
```

The migration for my database structure can be found here.

```
Schema::create('course_attendees', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id', true);
    $table->integer('user_id')->index('course_attendees_users_id_fk');
    $table->integer('course_id')->index('course_attendees_courses_id_fk');
    $table->boolean('mijnafas');
});

Schema::create('courses', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id', true);
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('subject');
    $table->string('presenter');
    $table->date('start_date')->nullable()->comment('Set to not null later');
    $table->date('end_date')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('points', 4)->nullable();
    $table->string('location');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('id', true);
    $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('course_attendees', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->foreign('course_id', 'course_attendees_courses_id_fk')->references('id')->on('courses')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
    $table->foreign('user_id', 'course_attendees_users_id_fk')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
});
```

I noticed when just calling `$test->attendedCourses` it retrieves the filtered collection. The problem with this is that I can't apply the scopes on this.

**Questions**

- How does it come that it will not sum the filtered collection?
- How can I make it so that it will filter this collection accordingly?

Comment: Can you show us the external scope of your Category?

Comment: @ChinLeung Updated my question.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it locally but I've been getting the correct answer for both external **true** and **false**. Try to do the following: `$test->attendedCourses()->count()`, `$test->attendedCourses()->external(false)->count()` and `$test->attendedCourses()->external(true)->count()`, do the numbers add up correctly?

Comment: @ChinLeung Nope. The numbers add up correctly from the `external` scope. But but the `$test->attendedCourses()->count()` returns everything, not using the `attendedCoursesInYears` scope for some reason.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean... Well your attendedCoursesInYears is filtering the users that has taken a course in the years X-Y, but it's not filtering the courses by the year it's taken. The scope should be done on your pivot table instead.

Comment: @ChinLeung How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `scopeAttendedCoursesInYears` method in your User class is to scope out the users who took the courses in the specific years and not scope out the courses that were taken during the years.

To do what you want, you could add a parameter to your relation to filter out the pivot table instead of your users table:

```
public function attendedCourses(array $years = null)
{
    $query = $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_user');

    if ($years) {
        $query->whereRaw('YEAR(end_date) IN (?)', [
            'years' => implode(',', $years)
        ]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Then you could achieve your result like this:

```
$user = User::find(123);

$user->attendedCourses($years)->external(false)->sum('points');
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this the only way? I'd like to have the `attendedCourses` filtered before I sum the points. Something like using a scope in my controller. This because I want the fields as columns so I can order and access them easily without too many if statements in a view.

Comment: @Bas What do you mean? They are filtered.

Comment: The result of `$user->attendedCourses($years)->external(false)->sum('points')` should be an attribute/column in the `User` model. When wanting to collect a whole list of users, I'd like to have this data as column/attribute. This so I can also re-order the list quickly. This is why I was hoping I could do it with an scope.

Comment: @Bas I'm not quite sure to understand your database structure, could you include some migration files so I can reproduce your structure in my local environment?